# The Fibonacci Rectangular Prism Sequence

Tags: code-golf, sequence, fibonacci, subsequence

## What is the *Fibonacci Rectangular Prism Sequence*?

The Fibonacci Rectangular Prism Sequence is a sequence derived from the Fibonacci sequence starting with one. The first 3 numbers of the Fibonacci sequence (starting with one) are 1, 1, and 2, so the first number of the Fibonacci Rectangular Prism Sequence is the square of the diagonal length of a rectangular prism (X in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3nrm.png)) with the dimensions 1x1x2. The next number of the Fibonacci Rectangular Prism Sequence is the square of the diagonal length of a prism with the dimensions 1x2x3, followed by the square of the diagonal of 2x3x5, and so on. The formula for each number in the series would be [A127546](https://oeis.org/A127546):
$$a(n)={F_n}^2 + {F_{n+1}}^2 + {F_{n+2}}^2$$
where \$F_n\$ is the nth number of the Fibonacci sequence. The convention is that \$F_0\$ is 0, and \$F_1\$ is 1. (See [A000045](https://oeis.org/A000045) for more information about the Fibonacci sequence.)

## Your Challenge:

Write code that takes an index \$n\$ and outputs the \$n\$'th element of the sequence. It’s [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code wins!

## Test cases:

```
0 ==> 2
1 ==> 6
2 ==> 14
3 ==> 38
4 ==> 98
5 ==> 258
6 ==> 674
7 ==> 1766
8 ==> 4622
9 ==> 12102
10 ==> 31682
```

## Leaderboard:

```js
var QUESTION_ID=214423,OVERRIDE_USER=98932,ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;function answersUrl(d){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+d+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(d,e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+e.join(";")+"/comments?page="+d+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(d){answers.push.apply(answers,d.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],d.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var f=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(f),answers_hash[f]=e}),d.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(d){d.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),d.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=function(){var d=String.raw`h\d`,e=String.raw`\-?\d+\.?\d*`,f=String.raw`[^\n<>]*`,g=String.raw`<s>${f}</s>|<strike>${f}</strike>|<del>${f}</del>`,h=String.raw`[^\n\d<>]*`,j=String.raw`<[^\n<>]+>`;return new RegExp(String.raw`<${d}>`+String.raw`\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?`+String.raw`(${e})`+String.raw`(?=`+String.raw`${h}`+String.raw`(?:(?:${g}|${j})${h})*`+String.raw`</${d}>`+String.raw`)`)}(),OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;function getAuthorName(d){return d.owner.display_name}function process(){var d=[];answers.forEach(function(n){var o=n.body;n.comments.forEach(function(q){OVERRIDE_REG.test(q.body)&&(o="<h1>"+q.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var p=o.match(SCORE_REG);p&&d.push({user:getAuthorName(n),size:+p[2],language:p[1],link:n.share_link})}),d.sort(function(n,o){var p=n.size,q=o.size;return p-q});var e={},f=1,g=null,h=1;d.forEach(function(n){n.size!=g&&(h=f),g=n.size,++f;var o=jQuery("#answer-template").html();o=o.replace("{{PLACE}}",h+".").replace("{{NAME}}",n.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",n.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",n.size).replace("{{LINK}}",n.link),o=jQuery(o),jQuery("#answers").append(o);var p=n.language;p=jQuery("<i>"+n.language+"</i>").text().toLowerCase(),e[p]=e[p]||{lang:n.language,user:n.user,size:n.size,link:n.link,uniq:p}});var j=[];for(var k in e)e.hasOwnProperty(k)&&j.push(e[k]);j.sort(function(n,o){return n.uniq>o.uniq?1:n.uniq<o.uniq?-1:0});for(var l=0;l<j.length;++l){var m=jQuery("#language-template").html(),k=j[l];m=m.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",k.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",k.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",k.size).replace("{{LINK}}",k.link),m=jQuery(m),jQuery("#languages").append(m)}}
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list{padding:10px;float:left}#language-list{padding:10px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/codegolf/primary.css?v=f52df912b654"> <div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">{{SIZE}}</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">{{SIZE}}</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: By the way, a closed form is $$a(n) = 4\cdot\text{round}\left(\frac{\phi^{2n+2}}{5}\right)-2(-1)^n$$ where \$\phi\$ is the golden ratio.

Comment: I'll be pedantic and say \$F_n^2 + F_{n_1}^2 + F_{n_2}^2\$ is not a *formula*, it's a *number*. Would you consider writing \$a(n) = F_n^2 + F_{n_1}^2 + F_{n_2}^2\$ instead?

Comment: @Stef That's probably more clear; I'll do that.

Answer (score 11):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 6 bytes

This is not really interesting (but it is the shortest answer).

```
3r+f²Σ
```

### Explanation

3, range, +, Fibonacci, square, sum.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/9@4SDvt0KZzi///NzQy/g8A)

Comment: Surprisingly readable for a golfing language!

Comment: Ah, I forgot MathGolf had a Fibonacci builtin. Btw, not sure if you're aware, but you can add more than one input-lines and it will run each as a separated program: [try it online](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/9@4SDvt0KZzi///N@Ay5DLiMuYy4TLlMuMy57LgsuQyBAoaGQMA).

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 33 bytes

```python
lambda n:((3-5**.5)/2)**~n//5*4+2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHPSkPDWNdUS0vPVFPfSFNLqy5PX99Uy0QbqCq/SCFTITNPoSgxLz1Vw9BA04pLQaGgKDOvRCNNI1NT878RAA)

**34 bytes**

```python
lambda n:(5**.5/2+1.5)**-~n//5*4+2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHPSsNUS0vPVN9I21DPVFNLS7cuT1/fVMtEG6gsv0ghUyEzT6EoMS89VcPQQNOKS0GhoCgzr0QjTSNTU/O/EQA)

Outputs floats. Based on the [closed form by Lynn](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/214423/the-fibonacci-rectangular-prism-sequence#comment501891_214423), simplified to:

$$ f(n) = 4 \left \lfloor{\frac{\phi^{2n+2}}{5}}\right \rfloor + 2.$$

We further convert \$\phi^{2n+2} = (\phi^2)^{n+1} = (\phi+1)^{n+1}\$, writing \$\phi+1\$ as \$\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}+1.5\$. We could also try writing it out as \$2.61803398875...\$ to some precision. The limited precision of floats will cause deviations for large enough outputs for any version of this solution.

**44 bytes**

```python
f=lambda n:2*(n<1)or(f(n-1)+f(n-2))*2-f(n-3)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcsxDoAgDEDR3VN0pBgSqRvRw2AUbaKFEBZPX2X6b/nlbVcWUk3rHZ9tjyCBrJHFY64mGXEexx5CtOS6ZtSUKzCwQI1yHsZPGAaAUlna/zCi0gc)

An alternative recursive formula that gets rid of the \$(-1)^n\$ term by recursing one step further back.

$$ f(n) = 2f(n-1) + 2f(n-2)-f(n-3)$$

where \$f(n)=2\$ for \$n<1\$.

**44 bytes**

```python
f=lambda n:2*(n<1)or 3*f(n-1)-f(n-2)+n%2*4-2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FckxCoAwDADA3VdkEZJKwUanoo@paLSgaSkuvr7qdMPl5z6Scq0yn@Fa1gDq2aBOjlKBwQiqdWR/mDpt2YyWq3wXISqUoPuGriffAOQS9UbBSFT5BQ)

Uses a recursive formula, with base case \$f(-1)=f(0)=2\$. Writes `n%2*4-2` for `-2*(-1)**n`.

Comment: Cool! Is there an obvious reason why you can seemingly "replace" the 2(-1)^n term with floor?

Comment: @Lynn I'm not quite sure, but the exponential estimate alternates undershooting and overshooting so rounding alternates up and down, I think because like the Fibonacci formula, the omitted conjugate term \$c^n\$ where \$c\$ is negative and has absolute value less than one. And the `2(-1)^n` was contributing the opposite alternation (\$\frac{1}{2} (-1)^n \$ inside the multiplier of 4), so they canceled to flooring which just goes down.

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES6), 34 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to [@user](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95792/user) and 3 more bytes thanks to [@xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor)*

The following recursive formula is given for \$n>3\$ on [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A127546), but it actually works for \$n>1\$:

$$a(n) = 3a(n-1)-a(n-2)-2(-1)^n$$

As noticed by xnor, we can also make it work for \$a(1)\$ by defining \$a(-1)=a(0)=2\$.

```javascript
f=n=>n<1?2:3*f(n-1)-f(n-2)+n%2*4-2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcxBDoIwEEbhPaeYBSQdmhpbXQnFq9AgNRryjwHjpunZK6y@zct7h1/YpvX1@RrIYy4levgBvb2726WNCsayOXCs0bj2alyJsiqQp3NHoJ7sodZMqSKaBJss82mRpxqDqhMy72md9gfnkbsqlz8)

Comment: I think you can get [37 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zTbP1k7dyEw9Oi@2psZYK00jT9dQUxdEGWlq56kaaZnoGv1Pyy/SyFOwVTCwVshTsFEwBNHa2poK1VwKCsn5ecX5Oal6OfnpGgmJGirVebWaQKUq1UAzNGsTNK25av8DAA) by doing -1^n in a different way

Comment: @user Thank you! That `2*(-1)**n` was looking terribly wrong indeed.

Comment: Shorter base case: [TIO](https://tio.run/##FcxBDoIwEEbhPaeYBSQdmhpbXQnFq9AgNRryjwHjpunZK6y@zct7h1/YpvX1@RrIYy4levgBvb2726WNCsayOXCs0bj2alyJsiqQp3NHoJ7sodZMqSKaBJss82mRpxqDqhMy72md9gfnkbsqlz8 "JavaScript (Node.js) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>9</s> 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
2Ý+ÅfnO
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f6PBc7cOtaXn@//8bGgAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/R9ybJKfvZLCo7ZJCkr2fv@NDs/VPtyaluf/X@c/AA).

**Explanation:**

```python
2Ý       # Push list [0,1,2]
  +      # Add each to the (implicit) input-integer: [n,n+1,n+2]
   Åf    # Get the Fibonacci numbers at those indices: [F(n),F(n+1),F(n+2)]
     n   # Square each: [F(n)²,F(n+1)²,F(n+2)²]
      O  # Sum them together: F(n)²+F(n+1)²+F(n+2)²
         # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

---

---

For funsies and since I was curious, here are the ports of the approaches used in [*@Razetime*'s Husk](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214425/52210) and [*@Arnauld*'s JavaScript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214424/52210) answers:

**10 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage):**

```python
∞<Åfü3nOIè
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//Ucc8m8OtaYf3GOf5ex5e8f@/oQEA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##AScA2P9vc2FiaWX/VMaSTj8iIOKGkiAiP//iiJ48w4Vmw7wzbk9Ow6j/LP8).

**11 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)**

```python
₂Sλè3*₂®Nm·Æ
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UVNT8Lndh1cYawFZh9b55R7afrjt/39DAwA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/R9ybJKfvZLCo7ZJCkr2fv8fNTUFn9t9eIWxFpB1aJ1f7qHth9v@1@r8BwA).

**Explanation:**

```python
∞            # Push an infinite positive list: [1,2,3,4,5,...]
 <           # Decrease each by 1 to let it start at 0: [0,1,2,3,4,...]
  Åf         # Get the 0-based Fibonacci number: [0,1,1,2,3,...]
    ü3       # Create overlapping triplets: [[0,1,1],[1,1,2],[1,2,3],[2,3,5],[3,5,8],..]
      n      # Square each inner value: [[0,1,1],[1,1,4],[1,4,9],[4,9,25],[9,25,64],...]
       O     # Sum each: [2,6,14,38,98,...]
        Iè   # Index the input-integer into the list
             # (after which the result is output implicitly)

  λ          # Start a recursive environment
   è         # to output the 0-based (implicit) input'th value implicitly afterwards,
₂S           # starting at a(0)=2,a(1)=6
             # (`₂S`: push builtin 26, convert it to a list of digits)
             # And we calculate every following a(n) as follows:
             #  (implicitly push the value of a(n-1)
    3*       #  Multiply it by 3: 3*a(n-1)
      ₂      #  Push a(n-2)
       ®     #  Push -1
        Nm   #  to the power of the current n: (-1)**n
          ·  #  Double it: 2*(-1)**n
           Æ #  Reduce the three values on the stack by subtracting:
             #   3*a(n-1)-a(n-2)-2*(-1)**n
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 8 bytes

```
ṁ□↑3↓Θİf
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASIA3f9odXNr/23igoHFgDEx/@G5geKWoeKGkTPihpPOmMSwZv//)

```
ṁ□↑3↓Θİf
     Θİf    # fibonacci sequence starting with zero
    ↓       # remove first n elements (n = input)
  ↑3        # get first 3 elements of what's left
ṁ□          # square each of them & sum
```

Comment: Oh, come ONNNN!

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 34 bytes

```hs
f=2:scanl(+)2f
a n=f!!n^2-2*(-1)^n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgEADAe69Yb1oousfAl0TCEkmSLpL9f515aLx3rSI54j4u4qo3g3kh4JiV4oQWV22DSSyNCkOE/hX@QTfqQHB454I/jUw)

Uses the \$a(n)=4F^2_{n+1}-2(-1)^n\$ formula.

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 34 bytes

```hs
(0!1!!)
a!b|c<-a+b=a^2+b^2+c^2:b!c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcM7CoAwEAXA3lPsdooo0VLMSfzAy@IPowRj6dldHZgVcZ@8V9heU8MVc5aA3SNtgdxZjHXu/jLWjWPRA9tJlsK1nTelBwKBOlOWlRkyfWX2WKIWEsIH)

Uses the \$a(n)=F_n^2+F_{n+1}^2+F_{n+2}^2\$ formula.

Answer (score 5):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 20 bytes

*-3 thanks to FrownyFrog*

```
1#.2^~2&(+/@$,$)&1 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/DZX1jOLqjNQ0tPUdVHRUNNUMFQz/a3JxpSZn5CukKRkoZOopGBr8BwA)

- `2& f &1 1` Execute f `n` times with `2` as left argument and `1 1` as right argument.
- `+/@$,$` Sum first `2` elements of the list, and prepend it to itself
- `1#.2^~` Square and sum.

Comment: `1#.2^~2&(+/@$,$)&1 1`

Comment: @FrownyFrog that's clever! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 9 bytes

```
!Ẋoṁ□ėΘİf
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARwA4/9odXNr//8h4bqKb@G5geKWocSXzpjEsGb///85)

1-indexed.

### Explanation

```
!Ẋoṁ□ėΘİf
       İf infinite fibonacci sequence
      Θ   prepend a 0
 Ẋo       map the following over triplets of values
     ė    make list of 3 elements
   ṁ□     sum their squares
!         index into this list using input
```

Comment: [Gotcha!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214431/95126)

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>24</s> 23 bytes

```
Ｆ²⊞υ²ＦＮ⊞υ⁻⊗Σ…⮌υ²§υ±³Ｉ⊟υ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY2xDsIgFEV3v4LxkehS4@RkcOlgQ/QLKH1KEwrNg9fo1yO4uNzh3Jx7rTNko/GlPCMJ6KTQnBzwXnTyvPuxPqycB15GJJD//jYHTnCNPHqc4MELqI/1qFxc4Y4bUkJg2XZkzUvuw4TvJg74MhnhWHm90DSHDMqkDLqa3GApp3LY/Bc) Link is to verbose version of code Uses @xnor's recurrence relation. Explanation:

```
Ｆ²⊞υ²
```

Start with the `-1`th and `0`th terms of the sequence.

```
ＦＮ
```

Generate as many additional terms as required.

```
⊞υ⁻⊗Σ…⮌υ²§υ±³
```

Push twice the sum of the last two terms minus the previous. (On the first loop, there aren't enough terms, but Charcoal indexes cyclically, so it still finds `2` as desired. I could have just started with 3 terms; it makes no difference.)

```
Ｉ⊟υ
```

Output the final term, which is the desired result.

Alternative 23-byte solution generates the Fibonacci series:

```
⊞υ⁰Ｆ⁺²Ｎ⊞υ⊕↨…υι¹ＩΣＸＥ³⊟υ²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ncw9DgIhEEDhfk9BOZNgomustpNqizUkngARwyb8BRiNp0corN@Xp63KOirXmqRigTg74jK9YmYgHRWYOVtDonoj/zAZEJH94Rp0Nt6Eap5wVcWA@GpnhI1p1B05O3W@TDLvoYJQpcKdPMj46aNNJThzJgfGTmcctrVLO7zdDw) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
⊞υ⁰
```

Start with the first term of the sequence.

```
Ｆ⁺²Ｎ
```

Extend the sequence until we have all the necessary terms.

```
⊞υ⊕↨…υι¹
```

Each term is one more than the sum of all the terms except the previous. I use base conversion from base 1 to avoid the edge case of the empty list.

```
ＩΣＸＥ³⊟υ²
```

Pop the last three terms, square them, and print the sum.

Answer (score 4):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://bitbucket.org/ngn/k), <s>27</s> 25 bytes

```
{+/t*t:x({x,+/x}1_)/|2\6}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/Nqlpbv0SrxKpCo7pCR1u/otYwXlO/xijGrPZ/mrqioeF/AA)

```
{                       } \ function with parameter x
                     2\6  \ 6 to binary -? 1 1 0
                    |     \ reverse -> 0 1 1 
       x(         )/      \ repeat the function in () n times
                1_        \ drop the first number and
         {     }          \ apply this function to the remaining list
            +/x           \ sum
          x,              \ append to the list
     t:                   \ assign to t
   t*                     \ square
 +/                       \ sum
```

I managed to shave off 2 bytes after seeing @[xash's J solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214437/75681) - please upvote their solution!

Comment: To make this work with other k's that don't support `|2\6`, `011b` can be used instead. [Here](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P82qWlu/RKvEqkKjukJHW7@i1jBeU9/A0DCp9n@auqKh4X8A) is a port to [oK](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok).

Comment: @coltim Thank you for your port to oK!

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <strike>37</strike> <strike>35</strike> 31 bytes

Nothing original, given the previous answers:

```
(((3+5^.5)/2)^(scan()+1)/5)%/%1*4+2
```

was 35 bytes, but Guiseppe got rid of four parentheses

```
((3+5^.5)/2)^(scan()+1)%/%5*4+2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/X0NDw1jbNE7PVFPfSDNOozg5MU9DU9tQU99UU1Vf1VDLRNvovwmXoSGXoeV/AA)

Comment: [35 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/X0NDw1jbNE7PVFPfSDNOozg5MU9DU9tQU99UU1Vf1VDLRNvovwnXfwA)...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen: darn, I first tried this version and it did not work on Tio...!

Comment: I think you'd accidentally left a ```f=``` in the header (probably from a previous version), which can interfere with ```scan()```-based golfs...?

Comment: [31 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/X0PDWNs0Ts9UU99IM06jODkxT0NT21BTVV/VVMtE2@i/CZehIZeh5X8A)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
3Ḷ+µÆḞ²S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARoA5f9qZWxsef//M@G4tivCtcOG4biewrJT////NQ)

I feel like it's possible to save a byte here, but I'm not sure how. (EDIT: Apparently the answer was to use 05AB1E; [@Kevin Cruijssen's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214426), which was written in parallel with this one, uses the same builtins in the same order but 05AB1E happens to parse it the way we'd want.)

You probably shouldn't upvote this answer; it's just a direct translation of the specification and contains no clever golfing tricks. I was just interested in how long it would come out to in Jelly.

### Explanation

```
3Ḷ+µÆḞ²S
3Ḷ         [0,1,2]
  +        add {the input} to {each elemeent}
   µ       (fix for parser ambiguity)
    ÆḞ     take the Fibonacci number whose index is {each element}
      ²    square {each element}
       S   sum the resulting list {and output it}
```

Comment: why community wiki?

Comment: @Razetime _ais_ always does that. He doesn't want any rep for some reason. xD Before he used to delete his account every few weeks. :)

Comment: An [alternative 8 byter](https://tio.run/##ASYA2f9qZWxsef//K@KxrjPigJnDhuG4nsKyU/8xMCDFuzvDhyTigqxH/w) that avoids the `µ` issue, but doesn’t save any bytes

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 47 bytes

I tried a few other methods, like the recurrence realtion [used by Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214424/64121) and the formaula provided by [Emeric Deutsch](https://oeis.org/wiki/User:Emeric_Deutsch) on the OEIS page, but a literal implemention seems to be the shortest.

```python
f=lambda n,a=0,b=1:n+2and(n<2)*b*b+f(n-1,b,a+b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcExDoAgDAXQ3VN0bAUTYTRymDaIkujXEBdPj@8933vciL2XdOplWQle0@wthQUuKjJjjTLaaK4wpuDNqzPp5W5UqYKaYt84zLIMRE@reLlwFenxBw)

Answer (score 3):

## Scala, 53 bytes

```
def f(n:Int):Int=if(n>0)3*f(n-1)+n%2*4-2-f(n-2)else 2
```

[Try it online](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/S6yAEfstQhm7ADhPeGG5aQ)

This one uses the method used in [@Arnauld's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214424/95792).

---

## Dotty, 84 bytes

```scala
n=>{def f:Stream[Int]=0#::1#::f.zip(f.tail).map(_+_);f.slice(n,n+3).map(x=>x*x).sum}
```

[Try it online](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Oy4an6b0RCuQp6yUQS2APA)

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>42</s> 38 bytes

Saved 4 bytes thanks to [xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor)!!!

```c
f(n){n=n<1?2:3*f(n-1)-f(n-2)+n%2*4-2;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZDNboMwDIDvPIWFhJRAojWBpu3SbIdpTwEcKggbh6UV6QEN8ezMMNqtkWzHn39ku@IfVTVNDXF0cMYdxat8TmN0uaB8NpImLpJxxqUep9Zd4evUOkKDIQB8M7D9xVZXW@elGSQDxUBkDNI9gwOK3KJSOyRipzCWKYlJQooNmlSovRz10qr6PHUxdHkJBoaw6N9l0R/eULYhg/9@Gq4VzbkDMk/Qutr2WLbR6/cIvv2254bcZqNPK4jvREOSLNkUfne57eOw0xLQD9gjns/0SC3S@wGWqvIv4dJhSkPCqAb@AqgjX7iQOeZZl3tjbLl2G4Nx@gE)

Uses [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld)'s formula from his [JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214424/9481).

Comment: A shorter base case with \$f(-1)=f(0)=2\$: `f(n){n=n<1?2:3*f(n-1)-f(n-2)+n%2*4-2;}` [TIO](https://tio.run/##VZDNboMwDIDvPIWFhJRAojWBpu3SbIdpTwEcKggbh6UV6QEN8ezMMNqtkWzHn39ku@IfVTVNDXF0cMYdxat8TmN0uaB8NpImLpJxxqUep9Zd4evUOkKDIQB8M7D9xVZXW@elGSQDxUBkDNI9gwOK3KJSOyRipzCWKYlJQooNmlSovRz10qr6PHUxdHkJBoaw6N9l0R/eULYhg/9@Gq4VzbkDMk/Qutr2WLbR6/cIvv2254bcZqNPK4jvREOSLNkUfne57eOw0xLQD9gjns/0SC3S@wGWqvIv4dJhSkPCqAb@AqgjX7iQOeZZl3tjbLl2G4Nx@gE "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: @xnor Nice one - thanks! :D

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-x`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 9 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
3ÆMgX+U ²
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LXg&code=M8ZNZ1grVSCy&input=MTA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Arn](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn), [16 bytes](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn/wiki/Carn)

```
╗¤û°œJ–¬▀ôƒìÚ„")
```

[Try it!](https://zippymagician.github.io/Arn?code=Mis0Kjp2KHBoaV4oKjIrMikvNQ==&input=MAoxCjIKMwo0CjUKNgo3CjgKOQ==&flags=)

## Explained

Unpacked: `2+4*:v(phi^(*2+2)/5`

Uses the same closed-form variant [@xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor) uses.

```
  2
+  Plus
    4
  *  Times
    :v  Floor of
      (
          phi  The golden ratio
        ^  Exponentiated by
          (
                _  Variable ≡ STDIN; implied
              *
                2
            +
              2
          )
        /  Divided by
          5
      )  Implied
```

Also for fun:

## [Arn](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn) `-l`, [22 bytes](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn/wiki/Carn)

```
ñf©¶─[•«DWLšií▬Xy®┐Vÿ"
```

[Try it!](https://zippymagician.github.io/Arn?code=djoxWzIgMnsqMy0gLTIqXzFeKyt2fS0+KzI=&input=MAoxCjIKMwo0CjUKNgo3CjgKOQ==&flags=bA==)

## Explained

Unpacked: `v:1[2 2{*3- -2*_1^++v}->+2`

Sequence definition, the `-l` flag returns the last entry

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 39 bytes

```
K`_¶_
"$+"+L$`(_+¶)(_+)
$2$1$&
%`_
$=
_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/3zsh/tC2eC4lFW0lbR@VBI147UPbNIGkJpeKkYqhihqXakI8l4otV/z//6YA) No test suite because of the way the program uses history. Explanation:

```
K`_¶_
```

Replace the input with the first terms (in unary) of the Fibonacci sequence.

```
"$+"+`
```

Repeat `n` times...

```
L$`(_+¶)(_+)
$2$1$&
```

... sum the first two terms and drop terms after the third.

```
%`_
$=
```

Square each term separately.

```
_
```

Take the sum and convert to decimal.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 51 bytes

```perl
sub a{my$n=pop;(2)[$n]||3*a($n-1)-a($n-2)+$n%2*4-2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY9Ra4MwFIXf/RWXkkHSKdSo0TZY@rqHve1NpLgtK8JMgolj0va3uyYbDNK8hHzn5J57tBg/i0UqMHbs3yxfzPQK3XmYkay10hxT0iDZXi7ZusNIJilJ/E3JI5IPdJ0n9LpMRsCLMHa3e1aj4NEww8He3jWGZgP1HmgbR/B/mtRBFkDqYJoHNHM0qwKaO7oNaeGzihAzn1aGk0ufV7Jwj8rxnNFw6a3303Rz18Z3zFJW0Zbw6EON2NcnZ28bZox6qWMkvjWpD@jI/zCgk7J151XyC3uDHfTeePUk9WTByZAke2@HLwNOXN0@XKN3JcXRRfXyxJcf)

Just a translation of Arnaulds Javascript answer.